# How to rearrange values from a string_agg

Tags: postgresql

> How to rearrange or simplify values from  a string_agg?
>
> For example, from this value 1|2|3|4|5|K  to this value K-5 or from this value 2|3|5 to 2-5..

```
SUBSTRING(string_agg(DISTINCT (trim(leading '0' from sgl.short_name)),'|' )FOR 11) as GRADE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `string_agg`, but a window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CAST (first_value(short_name) OVER w AS text)
          || '-'
          || CAST(last_value(short_name) OVER w AS text)
FROM sgl
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY somecol ORDER BY short_name);
```

Untested for lack of sample data.